# List and dictionary manipulation in python

Tags: python

working from a .csv file I pulled out the following

```
data=[
  {
    'English': 'swaziland',
    'Nepali': 'स्वाज ील्याण्ड'
  },
  {
    'English': 'varieties',
    'Nepali': 'प्रजातिहरू'
  },
  {
    'English': 'arbor',
    'Nepali': 'arbor'
  },
  {
    'English': 'bibek',
    'Nepali': 'विवेक'
  },
  {
    'English': 'configurations',
    'Nepali': 'विन्यास'
  },
 ]
```

I have figured out to get the above list from the file. this is a small part of the list. the list has about 10k dictionaries.
how do I pull out the value of "Nepali" when the value of English is given. I was trying to create a language converter. I am using python

Comment: It's nearly impossible for us to assist you if we don't see the code you're using. Please edit your question to include a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: although you say it is a csv file, you might consider reading it as json, That looks like a list of json records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you are looking for language conversion:

```
data=[
  {
    'English': 'swaziland',
    'Nepali': 'स्वाज ील्याण्ड'
  },
  {
    'English': 'varieties',
    'Nepali': 'प्रजातिहरू'
  },
  {
    'English': 'arbor',
    'Nepali': 'arbor'
  },
  {
    'English': 'bibek',
    'Nepali': 'विवेक'
  },
  {
    'English': 'configurations',
    'Nepali': 'विन्यास'
  },
 ]

english_name = input('Give me an English word: ')

found = False
for item in data:
    if item['English'] == english_name:
        print(item['Nepali'])
        found = True
        break

if found == False:
    print('Not found')
```

Result when the word you typed isn't found:

```
python3 test.py
Give me an English word: ask
Not found
```

Result when the word you typed is found:

```
python3 test.py
Give me an English word: bibek
विवेक
```

## Consider an alternate way of storing your data

```
data = {
    'swaziland':  'स्वाज ील्याण्ड'
    , 'varieties': 'प्रजातिहरू'
    , 'arbor': 'arbor'
    , 'bibek': 'विवेक'
    , 'configurations': 'विन्यास'
  }

english_name = input('Give me an English word: ')

if english_name in data:
    print(data[english_name])
else:
    print('Not found')
```

If you store your data as pairs of English and Nepali text as shown above, you will get excellent performance since dictionary lookups are faster than iterating through each item in a list.

Even better - store the data in a database such as SQLite and make a call to the database using Python. That'll allow you to add/remove data without changing code.

Comment: thank you sir for your help. but I got one error, it says TypeError: string indices must be integers in the first solution you gave

Comment: @BibekSapkota in what code and what line did you get that error? Note that both examples I show above have been tested with Python 3.8 so I know it works.

Comment: `data =pandas.read_csv("static/eng_nepali.csv")
    refined_data = data.to_dict (orient="records") ##this is a list with dictionary in it
    found = False
    for item in data:
        if item['English'] == english_word:
            nepali_word=(item['Nepali'])
            found = True
            break

        if found == False:
           nepali_word="not found"
           print('Not found')
` 
if item['English'] == english_word: (error in this line)
above is my full code

Comment: if item['English'] == english_word:  (this line shows error in my end)

Comment: In your code, you are not asking the user for an english word. In my code I am using `input` to ask the user for an english word and am storing that in a variable called `english_word`. Can you add a way for user to give you an english word and store it in `english_word`?

Comment: yes I pulled english_word from html page form. I tested it. it does take in the word provided by the user. I will  try out the other method you said.

Comment: @BibekSapkota Excellent. Let me know if you need additional help. If this method works for you, you are welcome to put closure to your question by marking the answer accepted. To accept an answer, you have to click on the check mark beside the answer.